# How to get an URL from SFSafariViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am integrating fitbit login-api in iOS with Objective C and I need to get the callback URL.

I am currently using `SFSafariViewController` but I cannot read the URL after login. Is it possible to get the URL from `SFSafariViewController` ?

Comment: Improved text for readability, as it was quite confusing. Also edited the title to better reflect the question.

Comment: Did you get something helpful? As I looked into the fitbit API, it clearly mentions that we cannot use UIWebView or WKWebKit for login. I am stuck on same page.

Answer (score 4):

In `SFSafariViewControllerDelegate` you have only one method, that can help:

```
optional public func safariViewController(controller: SFSafariViewController, didCompleteInitialLoad didLoadSuccessfully: Bool)
```

But it will be called only on initial (first) url loaded. If you have redirects and wait for some url in auth process - it will not help.
Then you should use `UIWebView` and implement `UIWebViewDelegate` delegate method:

```
optional public func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
```

But don't remember to be [ATS](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/)

Comment: Except that Fitbit explicitly forbid using UIWebView for oauth2 https://dev.fitbit.com/docs/oauth2/ - So you have to use SFSafariViewController and after it completes, you have to ping your server /web service to see if it was successful or not

Comment: @DavidGlance because they probably want to force you using `WKWebView`