# Safari ViewController with enabled address bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, sfsafariviewcontroller

I'm using Safari ViewController and address bar is disabled. How can I make it enabled so user can enter other url?

[image]

Here is the code that I'm using

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()           
    }

    @IBAction func showSafariVC(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com") as! URL)
        svc.delegate = self
        present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unable to edit SFSafariViewController 's URL as described [here](http://www.openradar.me/21381312).

And in Apple [developer site](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller) they mentioned that too:

> A read-only address field with a security indicator and a Reader
>   button

Hope this help!

Comment: Can I at least get the URL of the current web page?

Comment: maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33369164/how-to-get-an-url-from-sfsafariviewcontroller can help you.